# Bytebuddy - Arguments for agent premain

Tags: byte-buddy

I have a premain as below for attaching an agent to a remote process.

```
public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

    System.out.println("Premain");
    File file ;
    try {

            file = (new File("Agent.jar"));
            ByteBuddyAgent.attach(file,"18467");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Here, I want to pass the process id and couple of other arguments. Is there anyway to do this. Looks like it takes one single argument.

> java -javaagent:/path/to/agent.jar -cp jar-under-test.jar Foo.Main

How can i pass the argument here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to encode the argument in any manner you find appropriate. Instead of spaces as used for the arguments to `main`, use commas for example but escape all existing commas, for example by doubling them. In the agent, split by single commas and reverse the escaping for the resulting segments.